# r programming --- merge function returns column names with .x and .y

Tags: r

While merging two tables, I can't control column names in the merge result. To explain my situation, let me use mtcars data:

```
#load mtcars data.frame
data(mtcars)
```

Add a new column called 'car' that I will use as merging key

```
mtcars$car <- row.names(mtcars)
```

Now create two mutually exclusive tables.

```
small <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 4,]
med.large <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl >4,]
```

Now when I do a left merge, I should get 'small' table back as the two tables are mutually exclusive:

```
merge(x = small, y = med.large, by = 'car', all.x=T)
```

this returns 'small' table back but every column appears twice with .x and .y extension with .y columns all NA (since the two tables have no common records) and looks like the following

```
 car mpg.x cyl.x disp.x hp.x drat.x  wt.x qsec.x vs.x am.x gear.x carb.x mpg.y cyl.y

 1      Datsun 710  22.8     4  108.0   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1       4      1    NA    NA
```

how can I get column names only once with column values from the primary merge table in this case LEFT table ('small').  I don't know how to avoid .x and .y. extension?

Comment: when merging, if there are columns with the same name in both tables that you are NOT joining on, they will automatically be given .x and .y. Solution is to remove those columns before the join.

Comment: That is expected because even though there are many common columns, you are merging based on just one of them. So, it is as if you renamed all the rest of the columns in one table to be different from the other.

Comment: you could use the option `suffixes = c("", ".y")` to keep the column names of `small` unchanged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If every column name is repeated, you can just use

```
merge(x = small, y = med.large, by = names(small), all.x=T)
```

If column names differ, you can build a vector of names in both with

```
intersect(names(small), names(med.large))
```

and pass that to `by`. Otherwise, if the two data.frames share a column that is not passed to `by`, you'll end up with `.x` or `.y` suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

After the merge (and in the case you dont have column names that otherwise include .x or .y) you can replace .x and .y by '':

```
   colnames(merged_df) <- gsub('.x','',names(merged_df))
   colnames(merged_df) <- gsub('.y','',names(merged_df))
```

Comment: This has a very funny/annoying bug: gsub treats the dot as a regexp, so if you have someting like "mixed" in your column names, you'll end up with "med".

It seems that you can escape the character with "\\.x" and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use join suffix from dplyr. below is an example

```
library(dplyr)
tableA %>% 
    inner_join(tableB, by = c("A_id" = "id"), suffix=c("_A","_B"))
```